# Show that $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} \approx \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

To show $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} \approx \frac{1}{n}$ where n is positive integer

So far I have worked to:

$=\frac{1}{2a}\cdot(-\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k+a}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k-a})$

It seems that there is still some gap to fill.

Thanks,

I've added the graphs of the summation (in color red) and 1/n (in blue) as N goes from 10 to 50.

[image: N from 10 to 50]

Comment: Regarding what you did: you cannot break the sum in two -- both sums you obtain are divergent. Have you tried a comparison series-integral?

Comment: @ClementC., I compared them graphically...I broke the sum into two because I kinda out of method...

Comment: Is $a < n$? or is there no restriction there

Comment: 1) one needs to assume $n \ge a$ to avoid a zero denominator. 2) In your transformed sum you sum over $i$ but there is no $i$ in the expressions after the sigmas. [Clement's comment is relevant, one would need at least some kind of telescoping of the terms before making the overall summation.]

Comment: No restriction on a, however, we rule out the case when denominator is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding what you did: you cannot break the sum in two -- both sums you obtain are divergent.

Now, you can get your result by using a comparison between series and integrals: the idea is that "$\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} \approx \int_{n+1}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2-a^2}$," and computing the integral is much easier.

**In more detail:**
Let $f$ be the function defined on $(a^2,\infty)$ by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}$. Since $f$ is decreasing, you have, for any $i > a^2$,
$$
f(i) \geq f(x) \geq f(i+1)
$$
and integrating on $[i,i+1]$ (with regard to $x$ this gives
$$
f(i) \geq \int_i^{i+1} f(x)dx \geq f(i+1).
$$
Summing from $n+1$ to $N$ (for any $N > n$), we then obtain
$$
\sum_{i=n+1}^N f(i) \geq \sum_{i=n+1}^N\int_i^{i+1} f(x)dx \geq \sum_{i=n+1}^N f(i+1)
$$
or equivalently
$$
\sum_{i=n+1}^N f(i) \geq \int_{n+1}^{N+1} f(x)dx \geq \sum_{i=n+2}^{N+1} f(i).
$$
Now, we let $N$ go to $\infty$ (which is allowed as "everything there is convergent"):
$$
\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f(i) \geq \int_{n+1}^{\infty} f(x)dx \geq \sum_{i=n+2}^{\infty} f(i).
$$
Reorganizing the inequalities:
$$
f(n+1) + \int_{n+1}^{\infty} f(x)dx \geq \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} f(i) \geq \int_{n+1}^{\infty} f(x)dx
$$
so it is now sufficient to handle the integral (that you can easily compute) to show its asymptotic behavior; and to show that the term $f(n+1)$ is negligible in front of the integral (which is immediate)

Comment: Thanks @Clement C., your formular is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a decreasing sequence, you can estimate the sum by integrals.

$$\int_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 - a^2} dx < \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 - a^2} < \int_{n}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2-a^2}dx$$

You can evaluate the integral $$\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 - a^2} dx$$ via the decomposition you attempted in the sum,

$$\int_b^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 -a^2} dx = \lim_{c\to \infty} \frac{1}{2a} \int_{b}^c \left( \frac{1}{x-a} - \frac{1}{x+a}\right) dx = \lim_{c\to\infty} \frac{1}{2a} \left( \ln\left(\frac{c-a}{c+a}\right) - \ln\left(\frac{b-a}{b+a}\right) \right) = -\frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{b-a}{b+a} \right).$$

Replacing $b=n$, we see that the right inequaltity becomes $$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 -a^2} < - \frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{n-a}{n+a} \right) .$$

This may not seem like a lot, but we are almost done,

$$\frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{n-a}{n+a} \right) = \frac{1}{2a}\ln\left( 1-\frac{a}{n+a}\right),$$ so the left hand side goes to zero as $n \to \infty$. I particular, the arguments in the natural log approach $1$. Let's use a linear approximation of $\ln(1+x)$ to get an asymptotic.

$\frac{d}{dx} \ln(1+x) = \frac{1}{1+x}$, so we have $ln(1+x) = \ln(1) + \frac{1}{2} x + o(x^2)$, rather $\ln(1+x) \approx \frac{1}{2} x$.

Thus, 
$$\frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{n-a}{n+a} \right) = \frac{1}{2a}\ln\left( 1-\frac{a}{n+a}\right) \approx - \frac{1}{4(n+a)},$$ which means the left and right hand sides of our original inequality are asymptotically $\frac{1}{4(n+1+a)}$ and $\frac{1}{4(n+a)}$ respectively.

Hence dividing both sides by $\frac{1}{4(n+a)}$ we have:

$$-(4(n+a)) \frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{n+1-a}{n+1+a} \right) < (4(n+a)) \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 -a^2} < - (4(n+a)) \frac{1}{2a} \ln\left( \frac{n-a}{n+a} \right),$$

and the left and right hand sides of the inequality go to $1$ as $n\to \infty$. Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2 -a^2}}{1/(4(n+a))}=1.$$

Thus $$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} \approx \frac{1}{4(n+a)} \approx \frac{1}{4n}.$$

Comment: using the integral test formular provided by you, I get that the summation $\approx$ 1/n. But the formular isn't what's written in the book...

Comment: This seems to me the most straight forward way to go about it. Which formula do you mean?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If $f(x)$ is a decreasing, positive, continuous function, and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ converges, then the following is true: $$\int_{n+1}^\infty f(x) dx < \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f(i) < \int_{n}^\infty f(x) dx$$ but also $$\int_{n+1}^\infty f(x) dx < \sum_{i=n+1}^\infty f(i) < f(n+1) + \int_{n+1}^\infty f(x) dx.$$

The first set of inequalities follow from the second, since $f(n+1) < \int_{n}^{n+1} f(x) dx$ ($f$ is decreasing).

Answer (score 2):

Using what you wrote $$S_n=\frac{1}{2a}\Big(\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i-a}-\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i+a}\Big)$$ This can write $$S_n=\frac{H_{a+n}-H_{n-a}}{2 a}$$ where appear [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). As given in the Wikipedia page, their asymptotic expansion is given by

$$H_n =\ln{n}+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2\,k\, n^{2k}}=\ln{n}+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+\frac{1}{120n^4}-\cdots$$ Limiting to second order, we then have $$H_{a+n}-H_{n-a}=\log\left(\frac{n+a}{n-a}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{n+a}-\frac{1}{n-a}\right)+\frac{1}{12} \left(\frac{1}{(n-a)^2}-\frac{1}{(n+a)^2}\right)$$ $$H_{a+n}-H_{n-a}=\log\left(\frac{n+a}{n-a}\right)-\frac{a}{n^2-a^2}+\frac{a n}{3 \left(n^2-a^2\right)^2}$$ Rewrite the first term as $$\log\left(\frac{n+a}{n-a}\right)=\log\left(\frac{1+\frac a n}{1-\frac an}\right)$$ and use the famous Taylor expansion of $\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ in which you replace $x$ by $\frac an$; for the other, use long division.

Limiting to order $3$, you will then get  $$H_{a+n}-H_{n-a}=\frac{2 a}{n}-\frac{a}{n^2}+\frac{2 a^3+a}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ and then $$S_n=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+\frac{2 a^2+1}{6 
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: Claude, this is the best answer, I believe, to this question.  +1  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} 
\approx \frac{1}{n}
$

Start with the sum.

$s(n)
=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2-a^2} 
$.

Find a sum
that sort of looks like it
but sums to $\frac1{n}$.

$t(n)
=\frac1{n}
=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{i-1}-\frac1{i}) 
=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i(i-1)} 
$.

Get their difference
and show that it
tends to zero
faster than $1/n$.

$\begin{array}\\
t(n)-s(n)
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{i(i-1)} -\frac{1}{i^2-a^2} \right)\\
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(i^2-a^2)-i(i-1)}{i(i-1)(i^2-a^2)}\\
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{i^2-a^2-i^2+i}{i(i-1)(i^2-a^2)}\\
&=\sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{i-a^2}{i(i-1)(i^2-a^2)}\\
\text{if } n > a^2\\
t(n)-s(n)
&> 0\\
\text{and}\\
t(n)-s(n)
&< \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{i}{i(i-1)(i^2-a^2)}\\
&= \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(i-1)(i^2-a^2)}\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{i((i+1)^2-a^2)}\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{i(i^2+2i+1-a^2)}\\
&< \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{i(i^2+i)}
\qquad\text{(now I just have to show that this is }O(1/n^2)\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{i^2(i+1)}\\
&< \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(i-1)i(i+1)}\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac1{i-1}(\dfrac{1}{i}-\dfrac{1}{i+1})\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac1{i(i-1)}-\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(i-1)(i+1)}\\
&= \sum_{i=n}^{\infty} (\dfrac1{i-1}-\dfrac1{i})
-\frac12\sum_{i=n}^{\infty} (\dfrac1{i-1}-\dfrac1{i+1})\\
&= \dfrac1{n-1}-\frac12(\dfrac1{n-1}+\dfrac1{n})\\
&= \frac12(\dfrac1{n-1}-\dfrac1{n})\\
&= \dfrac1{2n(n-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$0
< \dfrac1{n}-s(n)
< \dfrac1{2n(n-1)}
$.